# Homework - length contraction ($\gamma$ and $u$ are unknown)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity

I am very sorry for posting these problems in this forum, but i don't know where to post otherwise... I have a weird special relativity problem where i get a relative speed $u$ which is larger that $c$. I dont need an solution but rather some guidance towards my understanding of the special relativity...

> Two sticks (both with the proper length $1m$) travel one toward
>   another along their lengths. In the proper system of one stick they
>   measure time $12.5ns$ between two events:
>
> 1. right ends are aligned,
> 2. left ends are aligned.
>
> What is the relative speed $u$ between the sticks?

I first draw the picture:

[image]

If i use the Lorentz transformation and try to calculate the relative speed $u$ i get speed that is supposed to be greater than the speed of light:

Here is what i did: 
\begin{aligned}
\Delta x' &= \gamma (\Delta x - u \Delta t) \xleftarrow{\text{Is this ok? I don't think my system is in the standard configuration}}\\
\frac{1}{\gamma}\Delta x &= \gamma (\Delta x - u \Delta t)\xleftarrow{\text{$\Delta x$  is equal to the proper length (in $xy$ the botom stick is standing still)}}\\
\tfrac{1}{\gamma^2}\Delta x &= \Delta x - u \Delta t\\
\left( 1 - \tfrac{u^2}{c^2}\right)\Delta x &= \Delta x - u \Delta t\\
\Delta x - \tfrac{u^2}{c^2}\Delta x &= \Delta x - u \Delta t\\
\tfrac{u^2}{c^2}\Delta x &= u \Delta t\\
\tfrac{u}{c^2}\Delta x &= \Delta t\\
u &= \tfrac{\Delta t}{\Delta x} c^2\\
u &= \tfrac{12.5\cdot 10^{-9}s}{1m} 2.99\cdot 10^{8}\tfrac{m}{s} c\\
u &= 3.74 c 
\end{aligned}

In the solutions it says i should get $u=0.5 c$, but i get $u=3.74c$. I used the Lorentz transformation found on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_transformation#Lorentz_transformation_for_frames_in_standard_configuration). These are for the standard configuration, but in my case is it the standard configuration?

Comment: Your problem is in the second to last step where you assumed delta-x is 1m. If the moving meter stick has a contracted length of, say, ~0.8m, then it only need move 0.2m.

Comment: But $\Delta x$ is $1 m$. It is stationary in the $xy$ frame and is therefore equal to proper length which is said to be $1m$. Am i wrong? Please explain how am i wrong.

Comment: So when i first write down the Lorentz transformation $\Delta x ' = \gamma(\Delta x -u\Delta t)$ the $\Delta x$ here is not the length of the stick in $xy$? It is some sort of the path right?

Comment: @71GA, see my answer to your 1st comment.

Comment: You don't have to be sorry if you show that you put work into the problem :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a more physically intuitive way to do this in my opinion.  Note that in your picture, the longer stick has length $L_0 = 1\,\mathrm{m}$ and the shorter stick has length $L=L_0/\gamma_u$ because of length contraction.  Therefore, the time $T = 12.5\,\mathrm{ns}$ given in the problem corresponds to the shorter stick traveling a distance $L_0-L_0/\gamma_u$.  This gives the equation
$$
  L_0 - \frac{L_0}{\gamma_u} = u T
$$
Now simply solve for $u$.  I checked this numerically by the way and it gives $u=c/2$.

Comment: I know that $\gamma_u = \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-u^2/c^2}}$ but if i put this into your equation i dont know how to get $u$ out of it. How do you usualy do this?

Comment: If i try to construct this a bit diferently (looking at the distances), i get different eq. than you: $\Delta x = \Delta x' - u\Delta t \longrightarrow \boxed{\Delta x - \frac{\Delta x}{\gamma} = u \Delta t}$. Is this due to the direction of speed? Where should i pay attention to the direction of the speed and where not?

Comment: @71GA Yes you need to be careful about the sign in the equation.  In particular, note that $\Delta x$ is greater than $\Delta x'$, so $\Delta x - \Delta x'$ must be positive.  This means that your equation should be used when the symbol $u$ represents the negative of the speed, and mine should be used when it represents the speed.

Comment: could you try and help me with my 1st comment :)

Comment: @71GA Sorry for the delayed response; I see you've already found the answer in math.SE though.  Cheers!

Comment: I did :) Ty all :)

Answer (score 1):

> But Δx is 1m.

**The $\Delta x$ and $\Delta t$ you seek are the change of the coordinates *of the right end of the moving stick*.**

In the unprimed frame, when the left ends are aligned at $t = 0$, the right end of the moving stick is at  $x = 1m/\gamma_u$ (*the moving stick is contracted in the unprimed frame*).

When the right ends are aligned at $t = 12.5ns$, the right end of the moving stick is at $x = 1m$.

Thus:

$\Delta x = 1m - 1m/\gamma_u = (1 - 1/\gamma_u)m $

$\Delta t = 12.5ns$

and

$\dfrac{\Delta x}{\Delta t} = u$

gives the equation in joshphysics' answer

I think your difficulty here is not realizing that, to solve for $u$, you need to pick one end of the moving stick or the other and then find the change in coordinates of that end.

Comment: I understand the theory now, but the biggest problem i have is that i don't know how to calculate anything from the equation Joshphysics provided. I mean $u$ is also hidden in $\gamma$ and when i insert $1/\sqrt{1-u^2/c^2}$ i can't seem to get $u$ out of it...

Comment: @71GA, the algebra is a bit messy.

Comment: I know. I posted this in the math forum here: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/429318/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're in standard configuration.  That's not the problem.  I don't think you're properly distinguishing between the rod lengths and the distance between events.

Let's go back to the drawing board.  You have one stationary rod whose length is $\ell$.  The other rod has its ends traveling along a pair of inertial worldlines:

$$s_r(\tau) = \tau \gamma c(e_t - \beta e_x) + \ell e_x, \quad s_\ell(\tau) = \tau \gamma c (e_t - \beta e_x) + \ell e_x - \ell \gamma (e_x - \beta e_t)$$

This has been constructed so that the time component of the right-end worldline is zero when that end is coincident with the stationary rod's right end.  Thus, you actually *don't even need* to find the length of the moving rod.  We can just take our equation for $s_\ell$ and see when the x-component is zero.

$$-\tau_\ell \gamma c \beta + \ell - \ell \gamma = 0$$

We find that $\tau_\ell = \ell (1- \gamma)/(\gamma c \beta)$.  Put this into the time component equation, and you get

$$s_\ell(\tau_\ell) \cdot e^t = \frac{\ell(1-\gamma)}{\beta} - \ell \gamma \beta$$

Set this equal to $c t$, where $t = 12.5 \, \text{ns}$, and you should eventually get a quadratic in $\beta$, which you can solve.